# Geo search mysql

Tags: mysql, search, geo

I been following this [example](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) for Geo search in MySQL(Really great tutorial!).

This is what I came up with:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `geo_distance`(in _location_id bigint(20), in dist int)
BEGIN
declare mylon double; 
declare mylat double;
declare lon1 float; 
declare lon2 float;
declare lat1 float; 
declare lat2 float;

-- get the original lon and lat for the userid 
select longitude, latitude into mylon, mylat from locations where locations.location_id = _location_id;
-- calculate lon and lat for the rectangle:
set lon1 = mylon - dist / abs(cos(radians(mylat)) * 69);
set lon2 = mylon + dist / abs(cos(radians(mylat)) * 69);
set lat1 = mylat - (dist / 69);
set lat2 = mylat + (dist / 69);

-- run the query:
SELECT destination.*,
3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((orig.lat - dest.lat) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +
COS(orig.lat * pi()/180) * COS(dest.lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((orig.lon -dest.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance FROM locations destination, locations origin WHERE origin.location_id=_location_id
and destination.longitude between lon1 and lon2 and destination.latitude between lat1 and lat2 
having distance < dist ORDER BY Distance limit 10;
END
```

The problem is that I don't know what is `orig.lat` and where did he took it, perhaps I am missing some thing. Can you point me on my mistake or suggest me a good source for Geo search in MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SELECT query that is being built here is to find locations that are close (within 10 units) to a point - let's call it x

`orig` is point x, then for each record on the database, you're comparing with `orig` the `lat` and `lon` values to see if it's close enough to load.

In practise, let's say you're loading a list of nightclubs nearby for a user, `orig` is likely to be determined by the user typing in their postcode, or something similar...

If you are still confused, let me know and I can try to help more.